# How to pass data from one view to the other in a navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Okay so I am creating an app for iPhone using a navigation controller and basically what I need to let my `addviewcontroller` know what the user selected on the `addsettingsviewcontroller`. So when the user hits the save button it opens the addviewcontroller and when that is opened it needs to check what value was selected on the previous view. I can get it to do all that for me but the only problem is that when the save button is pressed and the `addviewcontroller` loads the navigation bar is no longer there so the user cannot hit the back button and the view's title isn't showing. 
Here is a picture of my [storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSTXd.png).

Comment: Share some code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using storyboard, let it handles your push or modal as you specified in it. Don't disrupt it by using code that upset the flow.

Declare this in AddViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *status;
```

Then, in your AddSettingsViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Add"])
    {
        AddViewController *addViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        addViewController.status = Selected_Status;
    }
}
```

Selected_Status can be something like:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.levelSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
```

Comment: This Worked!!! Thanks So much I've been working on this literally for 3 days straight!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
Addviewcontroller *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addView"];

controller.status = easy; // select as enum of easy, medium, hard
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps you !